# Is the complexity of this code O(n^2) or O(n^2 * n^(1/2))?

Tags: java, time-complexity

I was thinking the complexity would be O(n^2). Am I wrong? If so, could you please explain why?

```
 public int countXs(char[][] m)


{
    int rows = m.length, cols = m[0].length;
    int r = 0, c = 0, count = 0;
    while (r < rows || c < cols)
    {
      count += r;
      while (r < rows && m[r][c] == 'x')
      {
        count++;
        r++;
      }
      c++;
    }
    return count;
  }
```

Comment: worst case is O(rows+cols).  there's probably a bunch of bugs in the code.  i don't think it does what you think it does.

Comment: Do you mean the code with or without errors? :) It looks like a linear scan to me.

Comment: It is a computer science questions for programmes.stackexchange.

Comment: I see no reason this question should be off topic. Algorithms are in scope, this is a straight forward Comp. Sci. question. I agree with the OP O(n^2). It does not really matter what the program does, it only matters how it behaves. For fun the OP could time the application with different sets and graph the results.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, your code may crash because of `arrayIndexOutofBound` with `c` index.

Next, when you invest the time complexity, firstly, you need to define what is `n`. Normally `n` indicates the size of input, in this case `n` is the size of 2-dimensional array.

So, you need setup the formula to time complexity and specify the worst case of your code to find time complexity. Suppose that array `m` is `pxq (p + q = n)` and we denote `O(1) = 1`.

```
T(n) = Sum(i->max(p, q)) {1 + sum(j->p)(1)}
     = max(p,q) + sum(i->max(p,q)){p}
     = max(p, n-p) + sum(i-> max(p, n-p)) {p}
     = max(p, n-p) + p(n-p)
```

Based on [Cauchy inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality):

```
4*ab <= (a+b)^2 we have: p(n - p) < (p + n - p)^2 /4  = n^2/4
```

So:

```
T(n) <= n + n^2/4 = O(n^2) . Q.E.D
```

Read more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Comment: Look at the code again.  The inner loop only gets executed on the first iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Also, if there is no x, it's O(cols), not endless loop.

Comment: It is true that the error code is `indexOutofBound` however, if there is no `x` and if they use `while (r < rows && c < cols && m[r][c] == 'x')` , then it is an endless loop. Now ignore this issue and let the code run with an array of all `x` which I consider as the worst case. Do you agree with above edited answer?

Comment: If there is no x, then  m[r][c] == 'x' is false all the time.   Do you still think the while loop is endless?  I can't believe this is even a point of discussion.

Comment: Didn't you see the ` r++` inside the loop. If the there is no `x` how `r` can be increased to escape from the loop? MAN